# Windows 7 not alowing option to browse network computers

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-explorer

Prior to upgrading XP to 7, my network worked fine. Now, the Win7 machine cannot browse the Vista computer or the PVR. Vista can browse Win7 fine.

In Windows Explorer on the left bar only the Win7 (Andy-PC) machine appears under 'Network'. On the right, the PVR (DX390) and Vista machine (Susan-PC) are there but only with the option to stream media. How do I fix this?

[image: Windows Explorer - Network Devices View - Zoomed]

Comment: Are all of these devices in the same Domain or netbios Workgroup?  You can check in (My) Computer properties, in the Name section or tab.

Comment: All machines are on the same workgroup. I have attempted to set up 7 with the same settings already in place since the rest of the network works well - even the Vista machine can access the 7 machine like it should

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 is notorious for that behavior towards older windows(XP/Vista)

Go to advanced network settings from network and sharing center.

Turn on "File and Printer sharing"

Turn off "Password protected sharing"

Turn on sharing for lesser cipher strength networks.

On the `DX390` and `Susan-PC`, make sure you have shared the concerned files/folders correctly.
If its your home network, just share it with `Everyone`.

As a last option, try `ipmessanger`. It will allow you to transfer files over LAN. It wont enable browsing folders though.

Comment: Sharing etc is all turned on already and lower encryption set. Must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed now. I war messing with the network permissions and firewall settings in Control Panel. I don't know which one did the trick, but after restart, all works fine.